# How do you change the height of a material-ui fab?

Tags: material-ui

I wanna edit the width and height of my material-ui fab button. I have tried to change it by using `classname` and applying `styles`. The width changes but my problem is that the height doesn't.

This is the css code:

```
const dashboardStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    infoButton: {
        height: '20px', 
        width: '20px'
    }
}));
```

It changes the width but doesn't change the height. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use material-ui makeStyles:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  fab: {
    width: "80px",
    height: "80px"
  }
}));

export default function FloatingActionButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Fab className={classes.fab}>
      <AddIcon />
    </Fab>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: I'm still new to this but wouldn't that do the same thing? Also that's kinda the same thing as what I did, I'll update my post.

Comment: Compared to your updated post, it is the same. But as you can see in the Code Sandbox link i attached, it works. To try and understand what's wrong with your code, can you post your component where you used this fab?